# Javascript object accessor weirdness

Tags: javascript, object

so I've been coming across a weird issue with javascript objects. Maybe it's just a lack of knowledge (relatively newer to JS), or part of the weird world of JS, but here it goes:

Whenever I try to check if an object has some property, ie:

```
var someObject = {};
var someArray = ['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'cow', 'horse'];
someArray.some(function(animal, index) {
    if (!someObject[animal]) {
        someObject[animal] = index;
    }
};
```

now if I'm not mistaken, the expected output of this should be as follows:

```
someObject = {
    'cat': 0,
    'dog': 3,
    'cow': 6,
    'horse': 7
}
```

however what I'm getting is:

```
someObject = {
    'cat': 1,
    'dog': 3,
    'cow': 6,
    'horse': 7
}
```

wat.

Also, the issue is resolved when I switch to using the following:

```
someArray.some(function(animal, index) {
     if (!someObject.hasOwnProperty(animal)) {
        someObject[animal] = index;
     }
  });
```

WAT. Not that it's much an issue since I've figured out the above solution, I'm just curious as to if I'm not understanding how the object[property] feature works? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by WAT?

Comment: @AmitJoki Possibly this: [wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks that must be it, though will have a look sometime later, never gonna do it with 32kbps :p

Comment: thank you, @JamesThorpe:) every programmer should see that amazing video.

Comment: @AmitJoki Haha, yeah - that's not going to work :)  It's worth a watch - good reminder of all the stuff we need to remember...

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/the-birth-and-death-of-javascript this is also a great JS talk by the same guy.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the value in the object with `undefined`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the first iteration, it will pass the `if` statement and assign it thusly:

```
someobject['cat'] = 0;
```

On the next one, it's doing:

```
if (someobject['cat']) ...
```

which is:

```
if (0) ...
```

And `0` is falsey, so it assigns it again to the next index, ie `1`.

With the alternative, `hasOwnProperty` checks that it exists at all, even if it's set to `0`.

Comment: wow, can't believe I missed that >_< Thank you! I suppose I've always just thought about it being used the check if it exists, not it's actual value. Makes perfect sense now. Thanks again!

Comment: Will accept this answer in a few minutes when it lets me.